# Wordpress media uploader in widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I have created a widget in my WordPress theme to show an image. The widget works in so far that I can enter values and those display on the front-end.

When I select a widget and drop it into a widget area, the media upload button does not work. In the left pane of the WordPress screen you can select widgets you want to use. When I unhide (it was set at display:none) the code for those widgets and then use the upload button there, it works. I guess because it is called before the one dropped into a widget area.

I know that WordPress adds unique parameters to each widget so they don't conflict with each other. So, I think I need to pass a unique parameter to the .js file for both: #cc-image-upload-file and #cc-image-upload-file-button. But I have no clue how to do that.

So who can help me with this problem?

**widget.php**

```
// Image only
    class cc_widget_image extends WP_Widget {
        function cc_widget_image() {
            $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'cc_widget_image', 'description' => __( 'Select and show an image.', 'cc_language' ) );
            $this->WP_Widget('cc_widget_image', 'CC - ' . __( 'Image', 'cc_language' ), $widget_ops);
        }

        function form($instance) {
            $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
            $title = $instance['title'];
            $image = $instance['image'];
            $checkbox = $instance['checkbox'];
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', 'cc_language'); ?>:
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" class="widefat" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" /></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image'); ?>"><?php _e('Image', 'cc_language'); ?>:
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image'); ?>" class="widefat" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image']; ?>" /></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="cc-image-upload-file"><?php _e('Image', 'cc_language'); ?>:</label><br>
                <label for="cc-image-upload-file">
                    <input type="text" id="cc-image-upload-file" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image']; ?>" />
                    <input type="button" id="cc-image-upload-file-button" class="button" value="Upload file" />
                    <label for="cc-image-upload-file"><span class="description">Enter URL or upload file</span></label>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('checkbox'); ?>"><?php _e('Do not show title', 'cc_language'); ?></label>
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('checkbox'); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('checkbox'); ?>" value="true" <?php checked( 'true', $checkbox ); ?> />
            </p>
            <?php
        }

        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
            $instance = $old_instance;          
                $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']); 
                $instance['image'] = $new_instance['image']; 
                $instance['checkbox'] = strip_tags($new_instance['checkbox']); 
            return $instance;
        }

        function widget($args, $instance) {
            extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? __('Image') : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);

            echo $before_widget;

            // display the widget title 
                if ( $instance['checkbox'] == 'true' ) {
                } else {
                    if ( $title )
                    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
                }

            // display the widget content 
                echo the_post_thumbnail(array(220,200));
                echo $instance['image'];

        echo $after_widget;
        }
    }

    add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("cc_widget_image");') );
```

**media-upload.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var custom_uploader;

    $('#cc-image-upload-file-button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose File',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose File'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.live('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#cc-image-upload-file').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });

});
```

Comment: I am by far not a JS wiz, but have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17435077/1244126 . It appears that this might be your answer as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thnx Obmerk for the reply. I found another solution with a different script and it works :)

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
 function media_upload( button_class) {
    var _custom_media = true,
    _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    jQuery('body').on('click',button_class, function(e) {
        var button_id ='#'+jQuery(this).attr('id');
        /* console.log(button_id); */
        var self = jQuery(button_id);
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        var button = jQuery(button_id);
        var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
        _custom_media = true;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
            if ( _custom_media  ) {
               jQuery('.custom_media_id').val(attachment.id); 
               jQuery('.custom_media_url').val(attachment.url);
               jQuery('.custom_media_image').attr('src',attachment.url).css('display','block');   
            } else {
                return _orig_send_attachment.apply( button_id, [props, attachment] );
            }
        }
        wp.media.editor.open(button);
        return false;
    });
}
media_upload( '.custom_media_upload');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var custom_uploader;

    $('#cc-image-upload-file-button').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Seleccione o adjunte archivo csv de importación',
            button: {
                text: 'Seleccione csv'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function () {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#cc-image-upload-file').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }


        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Uploadcare.com widget in my blog. Extremly simple to embed, nice looking and they have a free plan, which is just enough for me. Here is the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/uploadcare/